# Magento is adding strange value at the end of media files

Tags: magento-1.9, media, redis

I have moved Magento 1.9.1.0 from one domain to another. Everything works fine except media files, magento is adding strange numbers at the end of file end before file extension, for example:

> media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/780x7809df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/h/u/hu_25.jpg

Is loaded as:

> media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/780x7809df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/h/u/hu_25.**1453999868**.jpg

When i remove those numbers and additional dot, file is being loaded normally.
I was searching for solution for more then a week now. I would be very glad if anyone can tell me where did those number come from.

Also i want to mention that previously this website was using **Redis** for storing user cache and session. I switched it back to normal Magento cache and session storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you have apache with mod_pagespeed enabled?

[Here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-cache-extend) is the description of "extend cache", that will append a string to your filenames. Filename should be different, but maybe that can point you in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you for help.
Problem actually was in cache.
After long research i find out that problem was in "Cachebuster" module. Disabling it did the trick.

Thank you again.